# Will equipment inside of bags scale up to the level when you open them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

[image]So I have various blue and purple equipment bags from dungeons and doing quests for the dark brother hood (eg sithis headpiece equipment bag), will the contents of the bag scale to when I open them, or are they locked onto what my level was when I received them?

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing. Mind telling us what mod causes that?

Comment: I don't think you understand my question, it's for elder scrolls online not elder scrolls, if there's anything else I can clarify, or I'm wrong please ask or tell.

Comment: No, I'm just blind. Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the item level is determined when you open it (and not when you receive it).

So if you gain such a container being champion 120 and wait until being champion 160+, the item level will be champion 160.

Source : my own experience.

Same apply to level below 50 (since you can go to gold coast at any level).